# How to turn off all notifications of Android Facebook app?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, notifications, facebook, push-notifications

There are many old/partial/... threads about this where I find none of them satisfactory and sufficient. 
I want to turn all notifications off of my Android Facebook app. 
It has not been possible before, so I did not have the app. 
I will uninstall the app if there is no solution for the task.

I have browsed all Facebook settings but they do not have anything about turning all notifications off.

I would like to find also System specific block for Facebook App i.e. do not allow it it to show me any notifications. 
It  would be great if you can do this without third party appplications.

Phone: Oneplus 2
OS: OxygenOS 3.1 (Android 6)

Comment: Can you mention what steps you've already taken?

Comment: My step is now unInstallation of the app. Facebook systematically prevents users wishes. I have contacted them but no satisfactory measures. There is no need for analysis of situation. The app does not respect users privacy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good alternative is to delete the Facebook app and set up a browser shortcut on your homescreen through **Contacts**.  BTW, your internal storage will be spared a huge accumulating burden as well.  I did this on two of my devices.  The only drawback is not being able to share from applications on your phone that might use it.

Comment: Can you include steps how to make the shortcut, please. Are you sure in Contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Current solution is the differential solution which I use because the company has no plans and/or motivation to respect the users privacy. 
The company tries to impress users by letting them individually change some features of the app, but does not let the user have complete privacy. 
There are several contact requests to the company but they are not fullfilled.

**Conclusion**: uninstall Android Facebook application.

Comment: this does not reply the OP, therefore I give +1. Because your answer is simply correct. I don't know any other app that request so much access to so many things and services in your phone. Not even apps from Google itself.